# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table '' that match the referencing column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a primary key `voucher_no (varchar(10))` and I am trying to create a FK to this table/column from another new table but I am getting an error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'apinv_hdr' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_invoice_cfdi_x_voucher_apinv_hdr'

I have several other FK's tied to this table/column - why would it react this way now?

Comment: what is  the primary key in the new table ?

Comment: please taste the structure of both tables along with constraints present on both

Answer (score 0):

Primary Key and Foreign Key data types must match.  Have you verified the column data types are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some `voucher_no` record in `another new table` doesn't exist in `voucher_no` in `main table`.
Below script may help you.

```
select *
from another_new_table
where voucher_no not in (select voucher_no
                            from main_table)
```

If above query returns rows, you have two options:

delete those records from another_new_table or
insert records into main_table